# How to delete specific data from firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I'm trying to implement a function that deletes specific data (based on id) from the server.

My function looks like this:

```
Future<bool> deleteData(int index) {
    _data.removeAt(index);
    notifyListeners();

    return http
        .delete(
            'https://*my address*/${_data[index].id}.json')
        .then((http.Response response) {
      return true;
    }).catchError((error) {
      print(error);
      return false;
    });
  }
```

The data is deleted locally, but not deleted on the server.
Instead I get this error:

> I/flutter ( 5517): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE
>   ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter ( 5517): The following RangeError was thrown while handling
>   a gesture: I/flutter ( 5517): RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid
>   value range is empty: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem -

```
Future<bool> deleteData(int index) {
      selectedDataId = _data[index].id  //new line
    _data.removeAt(index);
    notifyListeners();

    return http
        .delete(
            'https://*my address*/${selectedDataId}.json')
        .then((http.Response response) {
      return true;
    }).catchError((error) {
      print(error);
      return false;
    });
  }
```

Because i deleted my data locally, i needed to stroe it before in var and then use this var